# Your current session has been expired. While adding product to cart at cart page Magento2

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, magento2, cart

After adding the product to cart, it show "Your current session has been expired." at cart page and the product also didn't added to cart.

Sometime its add the product to cart but most of the times it gives the above address and mostly this issue shows with not login users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us the code  where you are getting error

Comment: I am getting this with standered flow there is no specific code for that.